# Change label data when view changes

Tags: ios, uilabel, uisegmentedcontrol

I need help on populating my uilabels. I have three uiviews and each have five labels. I need to change the labels data when the view changes, i am using uisegmentedbutton to change views..What would be the best approach? Thanks.

Comment: If you're getting an event from the segmented button and changing the views yourself why can't you change the labels data at the same moment? Why is there a problem?

Comment: yeah, i can already change views using this command: "viewPanel1.hidden = NO;"... but i dont know how to change the data in my labels,, i think i have to use arrays but i dont know how to implement since im new to ios prog..

Comment: OK! So is the problem that you don't know how to get a reference to the labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it in exactly the same way you got a reference to the views, e.g. `viewPanel1`. You need a property or instance variable for each one. Let's say it's a property. If the labels were created in the nib, you must make an outlet for that property. If the labels were created in code, you must assign each one to a property as you create it. Now you can use that property, which persists, to refer to the label it points to.

Let's say I have

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UILabel* label1
```

Then later I can create the label and put it in the interface:

```
UILabel* lab = ...
self.label1 = lab;
[someView addSubview:lab];
```

Then even later I can refer to the label:

```
self.label1.text = @"Bart Simpson Was Here";
```

Let's do it with an array of labels. We have:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* labels1;
```

Then later I must actually make the array:

```
self.labels1 = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Then still later I can create the label and put it in the interface, and add it to the array:

```
UILabel* lab = ...
[self.labels1 addObject:lab];
[someView addSubview:lab];
```

Then even later I can refer to the label:

```
self.labels1[0].text = @"Bart Simpson Was Here";
```

(because this is the *first* label added to `labels1`)

Comment: but what if i will be using arrays,.i have to do it like this.. 
if segmentedcontrol1, i will use array1 for my five labels, 
if segmentedcontrol2, i will use array2 for my five labels,
if segmentedcontrol3, i will use array3 for my five labels,. I will use three different arrays since i have three views.

Comment: You can do that, sure. Are the labels created in the nib/storyboard or in code, though? I need to know that in order to tell you how to do it.

Comment: Okay, so now each `@property` is an NSMutableArray. Let me modify my code in the answer...